# Layouting and Rendering content on NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have a code that on the main Layout is only my navbar and the children(that it is the page.jsx) and i need do use many providers on the project that i'm building, how can i do that? i need to do a new layout? because using a new layout it only gave errors
this is how my code is right now, and it isnt working/renderizing:

/app layout.jsx:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Link from "next/link";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Projeto Integrador",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <div>
            <nav className="bg-[#C8DDFD] p-4 flex justify-around items-center border-b-4 border-r-4 border-l-4 rounded-bl-2xl rounded-br-2xl">
              <div className="text-xl mr-4">
                <button className="focus:outline-none">&#9776;</button>
              </div>

              <div className="text-xl font-semibold">
                <Link href="/#">Logo do Site</Link>
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:flex space-x-4">
                <Link className="px-4 py-2" href="/localizacao">
                  Nossa Localização
                </Link>
                <Link className="px-4 py-2" href="/objetivo">
                  Qual o Nosso Objetivo
                </Link>
                <Link className="px-4 py-2" href="/#">
                  Perfil
                </Link>
                <Link className="px-4 py-2" href="/loginUsuario">
                  Login
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className="text-white bg-[#336087] border-solid border-2 rounded-full px-4 py-2 hover:bg-transparent hover:text-[#BB594E] transition duration-300"
                  href="/cadastroUsuario"
                >
                  Cadastro
                </Link>
              </div>
            </nav>
            {children}
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    </>
  );
}
```

app/pets layout.jsx:

```
import "@/app/globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { AnimalProvider } from "../services/context/AnimalContext";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
 title: "Projeto Integrador",
 description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function Layout({ children }) {
 return (
 <>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <AnimalProvider>
            <div>
 {children}
            </div>
          </AnimalProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </>
  );
}
```

app/pets page.jsx:

```
"use client";
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AnimalContext } from "../services/context/AnimalContext";
import PetCard from "../components/PetCard";

export default function Pets() {
 const { animais, getAnimals } = useContext(AnimalContext);

 useEffect(() => {
 getAnimals();
  }, []);

 return (
 <>
      <div className="p-4 bg-[#C8DDFD] min-h-screen">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4 flex justify-center items-center">
          Pets Cadastrados
        </h1>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
 {animais.map((animal) => (
 <PetCard key={animal.id} pet={animal} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

If it's missing some info i can provide it.